# How to set different stride with uniform filter in scipy?

Tags: scipy, filtering, signal-processing, scipy.ndimage

I am using the following code to run uniform filter on my data:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
a = np.arange(1000)
b = uniform_filter(a, size=10)
```

The filter right now semms to work as if a stride was set to size // 2.
How to adjust the code so that the stride of the filter is not half of the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what [`uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html) is doing.

In this case, it creates an array `b` that replaces every  `a[i]` with the mean of a block of size `10` centered at `a[i]`. So, something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):  # for the 1D case
   b[i] = mean(a[i-10//2:i+10//2]
```

Note that this tries to access values with indices outside the range 0..1000. In the default case, `uniform_filter` supposes that the data before position 0 is just a reflection of the data thereafter. And similarly at the end.

Also note that `b` uses the same type as `a`. In the example where `a` is of integer type, the mean will also be calculated at integer, which can cause some loss of precision.

Here is some code and plot to illustrate what's happening:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15,4))

for ax in axes:
    if ax == axes[1]:
        a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,50).cumsum()
        ax.set_title('random curve')
    else:
        a = np.arange(50, dtype=float)
        ax.set_title('values from 0 to 49')
    b = uniform_filter(a, size=10)

    ax.plot(a, 'b-')
    ax.plot(-np.arange(0, 10)-1, a[:10], 'b:') # show the reflection at the start
    ax.plot(50 + np.arange(0, 10), a[:-11:-1], 'b:') # show the reflection at the end
    ax.plot(b, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Yes, I was understanding the filter incorrectly. Definitely +1 for the nice graphs at the end!